# Export-Pfxcertificate command not available in Powershell

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, azure-powershell

I am trying to create certificate `.cer` and `.pfx` files using powershell.

```
$certroot = "C:\Script\Certificate"
$certname = "TestCertificate15"
$password = read-host "Enter certificate password" -AsSecureString
$startdate = Get-Date
$enddate = $startdate.AddYears(2)
C:\Script\Certificate\makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=$certname" -b ($startdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) -e ($enddate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) -ss my -len 2048
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? {$_.Subject -eq "CN=$certname"}
Export-Certificate -Type CERT -FilePath "$certroot\$certname.cer" -Cert $cert -Force
Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "$certroot\$certname.pfx" -Cert $cert -Password $password -Force
```

These commands are failing for Export-Certificate and Export-PfxCertificate as commandlets are not supported in the current version.

I have also upgraded the windows powershell framework version to 5.1.

Which specific version of powershell to be used to execute the commands?

Thank you.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: What happens when you import the PKI module? `Import-Module PKI`

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz- its win 7

Comment: @guiwhatsthat - i get "Import-Module : The specified module 'PKI' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory." this error

Comment: Modue PKI is not available for Windows 7. You can try what you can do with [PowerShell PKI Module](https://github.com/Crypt32/PSPKI), but PSPKI is not the same as PKI..

Comment: Sometimes Export-PfxCertificate doesn't like the output folder. Try another one and you can move the file later.